# Angular material form not working - mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to create simple app for managing configuration of our streaming device. However I can't get it working although everything should be ok - imported modules, tag directives... It's my first angular app and it's generated according to docs (last version of everything).

In .ts file I get json with settings from the server (for simplicity I'm working with only part of it). I build the FormGroup with FormBuilder and fill it with values. When I log it, it looks fine - FormGroups/FormControls are where they should be, values are ok. However when I try to present it in template, it fails with said error. Similar questions were solved by adding directive or importing module but as I said, I should have everything needed. Thank you for response, I'm so frustrated now...

EDIT: sorry, I forgot to include the data which I get from the server - I'm faking it in constructor https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdkrdr?file=app/app.component.ts

**template**

```
<p>streamer-configuration works!</p>

<div>
  <form *ngIf="config" [formGroup]="configForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(configForm)">
    <b>Conference:</b>
    <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
      <mat-label>Enabled</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="enabled" value="{{ config["enabled"] }}" required />
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
      <mat-label>Auto answer</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="auto_answer" value="{{ config["auto_answer"] }}" required />
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
      <mat-label>Port</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="port" value="{{ config["port"] }}" required />
    </mat-form-field>
    <div formGroupName="technology">
      <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
        <mat-label>Selected technology</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="selected" value="{{ config["technology"]["selected"] }}" required />
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit, createPlatformFactory } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { ConstantsService } from '../common/services/constants.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-streamer-configuration',
  templateUrl: './streamer-configuration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./streamer-configuration.component.scss']
})
export class StreamerConfigurationComponent implements OnInit {
  private apiURL: string;
  config: Object;
  configForm: Object;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private _constant: ConstantsService) {
    this.apiURL = `${this._constant.baseApiUrl}/xxx`;
    this.getData();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  private getData() {
    return this.http.get(this.apiURL).subscribe(config => {
      console.log(config);
      this.config = config["Conference"];
      this.createConfigForm();
    });
  }

  private createConfigForm(obj = this.config) {
    this.configForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      enabled: [obj["enabled"]],
      auto_answer: [obj["auto_answer"]],
      technology: this.formBuilder.group({
        selected: [obj["technology"]["selected"]]
      }),
      port: [obj["port"]]
    })
    console.log(this.configForm);
  }

  onSubmit(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { ConfigSectionsComponent } from './config-sections/config-sections.component';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input'; // <-----------
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule  } from '@angular/forms';

import { StreamerConfigurationComponent } from './streamer-configuration/streamer-configuration.component';
import { ManifestConfigurationComponent } from './manifest-configuration/manifest-configuration.component';
import { NetworkCamerasComponent } from './network-cameras/network-cameras.component';
import { CamerasIconsComponent } from './cameras-icons/cameras-icons.component';

import { ConstantsService } from './common/services/constants.service';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ConfigSectionsComponent,
    StreamerConfigurationComponent,
    ManifestConfigurationComponent,
    NetworkCamerasComponent,
    CamerasIconsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule, // <----------
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [ConstantsService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example.  I imported the code you have provided (minus references to missing parts) and the error does not reproduce. Please see this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p4lryk

Comment: @TomMettam sorry I forgot it, updated the question with link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liniik, three notes

1.- if you use interpolation, use single quotes between double quotes

```
//WRONG
value="{{ config["technology"]["selected"] }}"

//OK
value="{{ config['technology']['selected'] }}"
//OR
value="{{config.technology.selected}}"
//OR
[value]="config.technology.selected"
```

2.- If you use Reactive Form, NOT use "value", just give value to the formControl

```
//WRONG
<input matInput formControlName="port" value="{{ config['port'] }}" required />

//OK
<input matInput formControlName="port"  required />
```

3.-In submit function you pass the form, so, your submit must be like

```
  onSubmit(formGroup:FormGroup) {
    if (formGroup.valid)
      console.log(formGroup.value); //<--see how get the "data"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Stupid quotes, I don't know how I could missed that... Also about te second point - it is because the "connection" with the form object which holds the values for formControl, right?

Comment: Yes, if you use ReactiveForm its unnecessary give "value" (this happens also if use [(ngModel)]), else you are saying Angular make the things twice